# Перенос пользователей из Wordpress в Joomla

Tags: wordpress, joomla, cms

Может кто в курсе как перенести пользователей из сайта на WordPress в Joomla? Вариант: написать SQL-запрос. Но есть где-нибудь информация или может кто ей обладает, какие поля таблиц Wordpress (для пользователей) соответствуют полям таблиц Joomla(для пользователей)?

Comment: Попробуйте готовое решение из JED https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/cms2cms-automated-wordpress-to-j-migration

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать импорт через CSV в phpmyadmin.

Сделать экспорт обеих таблиц, посмотреть и склеить как надо.

Но могу сказать точно, что будут трудности с паролями. - так что если не переносить связанный с пользователями контент, то смысла в этом не много. Проще будет поставить на joomla компонент авторизации через соц сети и почти все старые пользователи без проблем зарегистрируются заново (кто-то через соц. сеть, кто-то по старинке)

Comment: Трудности возникнут из-за разного метода шифрования? Если это так, то перенести пароли не получится, я прав?

Comment: Честно я это делал достаточно давно. и уже не помню как формируются пароли в wordpress, с секреткой они или нет. Вообще можно поискать и готовый вариант прасера. Но вся суть в том а нужно ли это тебе.